# Show CA=CB iff A=B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I got partial credit on this homework problem and would like a solution so I can study for my test.

The question is "Show CA=CB iff A=B, C is full column rank"

I got the "if" part which is pretty basic.

The "only if" part I got wrong though, can anyone tell me how to do it?

I put...

assume $A\neq B $

$$CA=CB$$
$$CA-CB=0$$
$$C(A-B) =0 $$ which is a contradiction as C is full row rank. I see now why this is wrong, but can anyone give me a proof for the "only if" part?

---

does this work? assume $A \neq B$
$$CA=CB$$
$$C'CA=C'CB$$
$$(C'C)^{-1}(C'C)A=(C'C)^{-1}(C'C)B$$
$$A=B$$ which is a contradiction

Comment: For a (possibly non-square) matrix, what does its column rank and row rank tell you about its inverses?

Comment: I thought you couldn't take the inverse of a nonsquare matrix. Isn't that why we have generalized inverses?

Comment: Yes, you cannot "take the inverse of a non-square matrix." Perhaps, I should have said "possible inverses." It is not true that a nonsquare matrix $A$ has an inverse $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$. But we might still be able to find a matrix $B$ such that $BA = I$ or $AB = I$. See k.stm's updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $C$ is of full column rank, it is left-invertible with some left-inverse $D$, and $CA = CB$ implies $DCA = DCB$.

To see that a matrix of full column rank is left-invertible, you can use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: C is not necessarily square, all it says is full column rank. your comment did give me an idea though

Comment: @JoelSinofsky Wasn’t my comment, but Schala’s. You should tell us what you mean by $C’$.